# Pandas dataframe reverse increment dictionary in new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, increment

I saved a dictionary with different keys in each row and all values equal to 0 in a new Dataframe column.

**Starting from the end**, and depending on the value of another column (same row), I would like to increment this dictionary, and store the view of this dictionary.

Incrementing is fine, but storing the view doesn't work. In the end I have the same dictionary in the whole column.

```
Before
col1    col_dict
1       {1:0, 2:0, 3:0}
2       {1:0, 2:0, 3:0}
3       {1:0, 2:0, 3:0}

What i want:

col1    col_dict
1       {1:1, 2:1, 3:1}
2       {1:0, 2:1, 3:1}
3       {1:0, 2:0, 3:1}

What I have:

col1    col_dict
1       {1:1, 2:1, 3:1}
2       {1:1, 2:1, 3:1}
3       {1:1, 2:1, 3:1}
```

For example:

```
def function():
    for x in reversed(range(20)):
        #taking the value in the other column, and incrementing the value in the dictionary
        dataset["dict_column"][x][str(dataset.value[x])][0] += 1
```

I have tried to pass to list format, same problem.
I think it's due to the process of pandas.

Thank you in advance.

Open to any solution to do the job

Comment: you can use the copy of the dictionary for assigning to ```col_dict``` after incrementing the dictionary

Comment: Thank you, i manage to succeed, will post my solution for others !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy of the dictionary for assigning to `col_dict` after incrementing the dictionary. Reindexing the dataframe to ensure reverse increment.

```
import pandas as pd
import copy
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"] = [1, 2, 3]

col_dict = {i:0 for i in df["col1"]}

def get_dict(col):
    col_dict[col] = 1
    return copy.copy(col_dict)

df = df.iloc[::-1]
df["col_dict"] = df["col1"].apply(get_dict)
df = df.iloc[::-1]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Doe, I found a solution to my problem, may not be the best option, but as I don't need performances..

Here is my code, less efficient than his I guess, but for a beginner like me, might be more clear to understand (no offense).

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

def function():
    #to skip the copy for the first (last) row
    flag = 0
    for x in reversed(range(20)):
        if flag == 0:
            dataset["dict_column"][x][str(dataset.value[x])][0] += 1
            flag = 1
        else:
            dataset["dict_column"][x] = copy.deepcopy(dataset["dict_column"][x+1])
            dataset["dict_column"][x][str(dataset.value[x])][0] += 1
```

Comment: My bad, just wanted to give a quick response, will edit the answer with neccessary comments